# C warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration

Tags: c

as a absolute beginner in C, I just got this kind of warning after compilation of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "word";
    char s[] = "word";
   
    int cmp(buffer, s);

    return 0;
}

int cmp(char *s1, char *buffer1){
    
    size_t l = strlen(s1);
    
    for (size_t n=0; n<l; n++){
            
        if(*s1 == *buffer1){
            
            printf("OK \n");
                            
        } else {
        
           printf("sth is wrong up\n"); 
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Please, give me some advice specifically about this kind of warnings. I have searched SO but found more spohisticated problems of that nature only.

Comment: In the future, include the **exact text** of the compiler message. Among other things, it includes the line number where the problem is. Do not report things like “this kind of warnings.” Computers are machines. They are exact. Be exact when discussing them.

Comment: Please take some time to review your books, tutorials or class-notes about calling functions. Also note what they say about *declaring* functions before using (calling) them.

Comment: The compiler parses symbols in the order in which they appear in the file. When it encounters `cmp` for the first time - when you call it in `main` - the compiler has absolutely no idea `cmp` is, so it generates the error. You can fix this by either moving the `cmp` function definition upward in the file (before `main`), or including a prototype / forward declaration. This is one way in which C is different than C#, Java, etc.

Answer (score 2):

@Wojciech Mierzejewski

1. Remove the `int` from `int cmp(buffer,s)` when calling the  function.
2. Declare the `int cmp(char *s1, char *buffer1);` function above `int main()` so that complier should know that the function is present in source code.
   E.g.,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(char *s1, char *buffer1);
int main(){
    cmp(buffer,s);
}

int cmp(char *s1, char *buffer1){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the line

```
int cmp(buffer, s);
```

in `main` is not a function *call*, it's a (malformed) function *declaration*.  That `int` should not be there.  If you wanted to *declare* `cmp` in the body of `main` before calling it, you would have written

```
int cmp(char *, char *);  // declaration 
...
cmp( buffer, s );         // call
```

So, an easy way around this is to *define* the `cmp` function *before* `main`:

```
int cmp(char *s1, char *buffer1)
{
  ... // body of function    
}

int main( void )
{
  ...   
  cmp(buffer, s);
  ...
}
```

A function *definition* also counts as a function *declaration*, so if both the calling function (`main`) and the called function (`cmp`) are defined in the same source file, then you can define the called function before the calling function, and you don't need to use a separate declaration.